# Number generator loop crashing program

Tags: vb.net

I've added a loop onto my program to make sure that the program does not output a maths question that would be too difficult; meaning that I need the first value (The left number) to be bigger than the right one, or the question will output a negative answer. I have however obviously done it horribly wrong as it crashes the program.

```
    Randomize()
    Dim values1 As Integer = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))
    First_Number.Text = values1

    Sign_Box.Text = "-"

    Randomize()
    Dim values2 As Integer = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Second_Number.Text = values2
    AnswerTextBox.Tag = values1 - values2
    AnswerTextBox.Text = AnswerTextBox.Tag
    Do Until values1 > values2
    Loop
```

There's the code, I know the loop is wrong, however I don't really have any idea on how to work with loops at the moment. Thanks for your help in advance.

Code 2:

```
    Dim values1 As Integer = 0
    Dim values2 As Integer() = {2, 4, 5, 10}
    Dim randomizer As New Random
    Dim value2 As Integer = values2(randomizer.Next(values2.Length))

    Do Until values1 > values2
        Randomize()
        values1 = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))

    Loop

    First_Number.Text = values1
    Second_Number.Text = value2
    AnswerTextBox.Tag = values1 / value2
    AnswerTextBox.Text = AnswerTextBox.Tag
    Sign_Box.Text = "/"
```

With the code above, I am attempting to do the same thing, however I am getting an error of:

Error   1   Operator '>' is not defined for types 'Integer' and '1-dimensional array of Integer'.

Comment: there is nothing in that loop it should just lock up the computer, not crash.  all you need for a pair of random vals is `rand.Next(min, max+1)` you can define the return value's range using the Random class.  No loop and much less code.

Comment: I don't see any code in the loop. If `values1` is greater than `values2` it will loop forever. There's no code to try and get the values to be what you want.

Comment: You've got a typo in there.  Remove the "s" so that "values2" becomes "value2" in `Do Until values1 > value2`.  Horribly named variables...

Comment: I realised it may have been that. I think that came from copying and adjusting someone else's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate the loop completely. Think about what the upper/lower bounds for the answer should be, and have your `Rnd()` calls generate only the second part of the question and the *answer*. Then you can infer the first part of the question accurately. This eliminates the need to write a loop at all.

Additionally, it's not a good idea to call `Randomize()` more than once. Ideally, you can use the same Randomize() call for a whole program, or program segment. Here is the code:

```
Dim r As New Random()
Dim value2 As Integer = r.Next(1,11) '1 inclusive, 11 is exclusive. allows values from 1 to 10
Dim answer As Integer = r.Next(0,11-value2) '11-value2 keeps value1 from being higher than you want

First_Number.Text = value2 + answer
Sign_Box.Text = "-"
Second_Number.Text = value2
AnswerTextBox.Tag = answer
AnswerTextBox.Text = AnswerTextBox.Tag
```

---

Now for the original code. Your existing code crashes because the entirety of your loop is contained within this code:

```
Do Until values1 > values2
Loop
```

Nothing outside of this matters. Since neither `values1` nor `values2` ever change in that code, if they start out failing the loop condition, they will *always* fail the loop condition, and your code gets stuck there.

To fix it, you can change this code:

```
Dim values2 As Integer = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))
Second_Number.Text = values2
AnswerTextBox.Tag = values1 - values2
AnswerTextBox.Text = AnswerTextBox.Tag
Do Until values1 > values2
Loop
```

To look like this:

```
Dim values2 As Intege2 = CInt((10 * Rnd()) + 1)
Do Until values1 > values2
    values2 = CInt((10 * Rnd()) + 1)
Loop

Second_Number.Text = values2
AnswerTextBox.Tag = values1 - values2
AnswerTextBox.Text = AnswerTextBox.Tag
```

But again, that's less effective than avoiding the loop in the first place.

Comment: I've got the original code working, could you have a look at the second code and help me figure out why that may not be working?

Comment: Oh, I see the edit now to your question. To fix it, just change `values1 > values2` to `values1 > value2`

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, but using what you have, you could try something like:

```
Dim values1 As Integer = 0
Dim values2 As Integer = 0

Do Until values1 > values2
Randomize()
values1 = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))

Randomize()
values2 = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))

Loop

First_Number.Text = values1
Sign_Box.Text = "-"
Second_Number.Text = values2
AnswerTextBox.Tag = values1 - values2
AnswerTextBox.Text = AnswerTextBox.Tag
```

Comment: @j-melis That worked, sorry can you have a look at code 2, I can't seem to rearrange it correctly.

Comment: @Jurdun - I am not sure what you are asking/looking for on the second block of code.

Comment: @j-melis I need it to loop exactly the same as you just did. I've got most of it sorted, but there is not an error of: Error 1 Operator '>' is not defined for types 'Integer' and '1-dimensional array of Integer'. - I will copy the code that i have done so far

Comment: You should only call `Randomize()` **once** for your program.  The `Load()` event of the Form is a good place to do that.  As others have mentioned, using the newer `Random` class is even better.  You should reuse the same Random instance for your whole program by declaring it at Form level instead of inside one of your methods (or by making it `static` in the method).

Comment: @Jurdun you are comparing `values1` to `values2` when you should be using `value2`

Comment: @Idle_Mind - thanks for the information. I don't work in VB.net often, and I hardly ever use anything to do with Random.